# Simple modeling tools that integrate with Blender

Tags: modeling, texturing, add-on, import

I'm a developer looking to make some simple games using an open source game engine, but I'm brand-spanking-new to *both* Blender and 3D modeling in general. I am fervently reading [books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1498746454) and following YouTube tutorials to learn as much as I can.

But since I'm so new, and seeing that I'm excited to get some custom models loaded into my game so I can toy around with them, I'm looking for a model pipeline where:

1. A WYSIWYG-style 3D modeling tool helps me create pseudo-custom textured models, and export them as OBJ/MTL files
2. Then I import these in Blender and do some minor editing on them, then either leave the edits as saved OBJ/MTL files or convert them to `.blend` files
3. Then I load these files into my game

I'm doing this because there's a few dozen different models I'd like to use in my game, and it is going to take me a *long time* to get good enough with Blender so that I can create decent-looking models from scratch.

For human/humanoid models, I see that I can use tools like [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/) or [Adobe Fuse](http://www.adobe.com/products/fuse.html).

But what about everything else?!? What if I want to make a dog, or a table, or a tree, etc.? **Are there open source/free tools out there that will help me create "custom" textured models simply/easily, and that can then be exported and loaded into Blender?**

Comment: for interior design items, you can try http://www.sweethome3d.com, which can fit your workflow for 1 (see http://www.sweethome3d.com/userGuide.jsp#otherFeatures)

Comment: Thanks @m.ardito (+1) - but is their website down?

Comment: ? I just browsed, using the link I posted... it's up. But I forgot to suggest also some blender addon that could help you (like https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Curve/Sapling_Tree)... there are so many addons...

Comment: Thanks, yeah it looks like their site is currenty down. I'll try later tonight

Comment: ...it's up, you may be facing other issues...

Comment: check this http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/sweethome3d.com

Comment: Super weird, it is just me. But definitely nothing on my end (I have a good, solid network connection. Maybe something with my ISP. I'll try again tomorrow, and if that fails, I'll call TimeWarner Cable this weekend). Thanks for the suggestion, as soon as I can check it out, I will!

Comment: Don't forget blendswap.com, countless blender ready models.